# npx harhat compile and node is posing a version problem

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, solidity, hardhat, nft

So i'tried to run this command( npx hardhat compile) and vscode told me

WARNING:You are currently using Node.js v19.8.1, which is not supported by Hardhat. This can lead to unexpected behavior. See https://hardhat.org/nodejs-versions
.Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

- Invalid account: #0 for network: mumbai - private key too short, expected 32 bytes

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/

For more info go to https://hardhat.org/HH8 or run Hardhat with --show-stack-traces

And when i took a look to that url i understood that this year hardhat are working with node.js 21 so i tried (nvm-windows , npm install -g nodist , nvm install 21 ) and still getting warning like (     nvm : Le terme «nvm» n'est pas reconnu comme nom d'applet de commande,
fonction, fichier de script ou programme exécutable. Vérifiez
l'orthographe du nom, ou si un chemin d'accès existe, vérifiez que le
chemin d'accès est correct et réessayez.)
Any Idea What Should I Do

Answer (score 0):

The warning and error messages you received indicate two separate issues:

1. **Node.js Version Warning:**

   - You are using Node.js version 19.8.1, which is not supported by Hardhat. To resolve this, you should switch to a Node.js version that is supported by Hardhat. You can find the supported versions on the Hardhat website or in the provided link.
2. **Invalid Account Error:**

   - There is an issue with the configuration for the Mumbai network. It seems that the private key for account #0 is too short (expected 32 bytes). Ensure that you are providing the correct private key and that it has the correct length.

To address these issues:

**Node.js Version:**

- Install a supported version of Node.js [18.x](https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v18.x/)

**Invalid Account:**

- Check your Hardhat configuration file (usually named `hardhat.config.js` or `hardhat.config.ts`) and locate the configuration for the Mumbai network.
- Ensure that the private key provided for account #0 is a valid Ethereum private key and has the correct length.
- You may need to update the private key to a valid one using one of this examples below:(depending on which configuration you’re using)

#### Example 1: Using a Valid Private Key

- You want to fix the invalid account error by providing a valid private key for the Mumbai network.
- Update your Hardhat configuration file (`hardhat.config.js` or `hardhat.config.ts`) with the new private key:

  ```js
  module.exports = {
     networks: {
       mumbai: {
         url: 'https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com',
         accounts: [yourValidPrivateKey],
       },
     },
     // other configuration options...
  };
  ```

#### Example 2: Using Environment Variables

- You want to keep private keys secure and flexible, so you decide to use environment variables for the private key. By creating a `.env` file and setting your private key like this `MUMBAI_PRIVATE_KEY="yourPrivateKeyHere"` or you do this⬇️:

1. Set an environment variable for your private key. Open your terminal and run:

   ```bash
    export MUMBAI_PRIVATE_KEY="yourPrivateKeyHere"
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use a tool like `dotenv` to manage environment variables.
2. Update your Hardhat configuration file to read the private key from the environment variable:

   ```js
   require('dotenv').config();

   module.exports = {
     networks: {
       mumbai: {
         url: 'https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com',
         accounts: [process.env.MUMBAI_PRIVATE_KEY],
       },
     },
     // other configuration options...
   };
   ```

After making these changes, try running `npx hardhat compile` again. If you encounter further issues, carefully review your Hardhat configuration and make any necessary adjustments.